# Repeat header based on user choice

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a <strike>report</strike> subreport with a group and the option "Repeat group header in each page" checked. But I need the user to be able to choose whether or not to show the group header on every page, or just the first time the group appears.

I set up a checkbox to let them choose, but how can I use this to tell the report not to repeat the header during run time?

**Update**

Beeing a Subreport I can not know which page will appear for the first time and I can not restart the numbering because it is necessary for the report.

I'm using CrystalReports in VS2005 and coding C# in VS2010, I'm working for a company and can't upgrade.

I'm trying to use a FormulaFieldDefinition in C# but I don't know how.

Comment: I have found a solution I don't like, I have just copied the report and checked the "Repeat group header in each page" option in one of them, so in C# I just choose which one I should load depending on the users preferences, but I would like merging both Reports in just one rpt file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with a variable inside the sub-report.

Create a formula-field with following content and place it somewhere in the detail-section:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
booleanVar headerPrinted := True;
```

In the suppresion-formula of the group-header place the following code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
booleanVar headerPrinted;
```

The formula will set the variable to `True` as soon as the first detail is being printed.

So the suppression formula evaluates to `False` only the first time the group header is being printed and to `True` on every subsequent time.

So with a boolean parameter `{?GroupHeader}` to choose if the header should be printed or not the suppression-formula would look as follows:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
booleanVar headerPrinted;

If {?GroupHeader} And headerPrinted Then
    True
Else
    False
```

`{?GroupHeader}` = `True` would mean: Only show group-headers once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Crystal Reports you are using, but it does not look like there is an ability to specify a formula for "Repeat Group Header on each Page" under the Group Expert in Crystal 2011.

Instead, you might have to do a work around:

1. Create a boolean parameter `{?GroupHeader}` where true means "show the group header on every page."
2. Create a page header.
3. Copy your group header elements into the new page header.
4. Create a suppression formula on the new page header section under the Section Expert. 
   `if PageNumber > 1 and {?GroupHeader} = true then false else true`.

Comment: I think you need to reverse your logic.... like `if PageNumber = 1 and {?GroupHeader} = true then false else true`

Comment: @Siva then the new page header section would ONLY appear on the first page. I included the page number because this supposes that the group header section is still in place and handles the first instance of the group header.

Comment: I suppose false will supress the header and true will show the header so as per your logic when second page and user selection is true then you are supressing the header and when first page and user selection is true then you are showing the header.. so I thought your logic needs bit improvement

Comment: @Siva in supression formula false = display and true = hide.

Comment: Sorry bro... its a quite bit of time I worked on CR.. you are correct... Thanks for clarification

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it gets more difficult: it's a subreport so I can't now if the first page is truly the first page or maybe the main report is more than one page size and then I lose the header in all my pages... By the way, I'm still using Crystal 2005, company policy, something about "I'm too old for this shit" and that kind of stuff. Not loving the policy.

Comment: You can create a formula in the subreport. Start it with the `WhilePrintingReports;` and declare a `Shared` variable and populate that with the group name. Then create a formula in the main report and do the same thing, but return the variable.  Now you can access the group information in the page header of the main report.